# A function that accepts a sentence containing blanks and punctuation and returns a string with them removed

Tags: javascript, character, whitespace

I've started to solve this function but am stuck with how to start the function.
I think I have the variables right, I'm just not sure about how I should order my function. I know i eventually need to call `return punctuaionless` I just cant remember what else I need to do.

```js
var s = " ";
var punctuationless = s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()\s]/g,"");
function compress(){

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to turn your code into a function, then you are close. Make it so your function accepts a string, do the replace on that string and return it.

```js
function compress(s){
  return s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()\s]/g,"");
}

var punctuationless = "lskdj. 2lkj&#* 2.e.kfj slkdjf asdf";

console.log(compress(punctuationless));
```